# extract text values from a string like html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `string` (not `html` but `string`):

```
<div class="rTag">ATINA</div><div class="rTag">BELMOPAN</div><div class="rTag">DAMASK</div><div class="rTag">FILIPINI</div><div class="rTag">BANGKOK</div>
```

Need to extract text value of `rTag` so result should be a new string:

`ATINA,BELMOPAN,DAMASK,FILIPINI,BANGKOK`

Any help?

Comment: This problems looks like it can be reduced to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Since the syntax is something like XML, you should use an XML parser. Don't know what you mean with "not html" because *ML text is normally stored in strings, so that statement doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Or if you know for sure the structure won't change; some regex might also work. It probably isn't the cleanest solution tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set the content of #output to the new str, but you can do whatever you want after its joined.

```js
var str = [];
var content = '<div class="rTag">ATINA</div><div class="rTag">BELMOPAN</div><div class="rTag">DAMASK</div><div class="rTag">FILIPINI</div><div class="rTag">BANGKOK</div>';
var $html = $($.parseHTML("<div>" + content + "</div>"));

$html.find(".rTag").each(function(){
str.push($(this).html());
});


$("#output").html(str.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: The question mentioned it has the html as a *string*, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: maybe place this string as a content of a div and then try this solution

Comment: I don't know the source of the string nor purpose, but this sounds like a security nightmare to me :)

Comment: @MagicLegend, that's just an example, in reality the string also includes London, Otava, Stockholm...

Comment: I was able to get it to work with html in a string. I have updated the code.

Comment: You can use `.map()` http://api.jquery.com/map/ to build the array (rather than have an outer-scope variable and push)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing an HTML string into a DOM element so that it can be processed by javascript/jquery is a fairly standard process:

```
$(content)
```

will suffice without needing to add it to the DOM (and all that entails behind the scenes).

In this case:

```js
var content = '<div class="rTag">ATINA</div><div class="rTag">BELMOPAN</div><div class="rTag">DAMASK</div><div class="rTag">FILIPINI</div><div class="rTag">BANGKOK</div>';

var arr = $(content).filter(".rTag").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(arr.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```